Is it true that $∑ _{i=1}^n∑_{j=1}^n v_i^3v_j \leq C$ for some constant $C$ where the $2$-norm of $v$ is $1$?
Remark : In the edited questions n tends to infinity.
Denote by $v\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ a vector on the unit ball in $n$ dimensions that is $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\vert\vert v\vert\vert_2=1$.
Is it true that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{v\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n v_i^3v_j \leq C,
$$
holds for some constant $C$, independent of $n$.
The obvious upper bound of this nature goes as follows
$$
 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n v_i^3v_j \leq \left| \sum_{i=1}^nv_i^3 \right| \left| \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \right|
\leq \vert\vert v\vert\vert_2 \cdot \vert\vert v\vert\vert_1\leq 1\cdot \sqrt{n} = \infty.
$$
Taking the maximum on both sums clearly does not work, one needs to consider how maximizing one sum, effects the other.
I believe that this term can be bounded by 2, the reason why i believe it is because the one-norm is maximal for $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}1^n$.
But for that given vector we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n v_i^3v_j = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n n^{-2} = 1.
$$
There are examples for which the multiplication is bigger than 1, for instance $v=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0.5,0.5)$, clearly $\vert\vert v\vert\vert_2=1$,
but than we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nv_i^3v_j \geq 1.03 > 1.$$
Anyway, I struggle to find proof or a method to show that this is indeed the case, or prove otherwise.
Now that i think about it we can assume that all the entries of $v$ are non-negative.
So the question can be rephrased as follows.
Is it true that a constant $C>0$ exists such that
$$
 \lim_{n->\infty}\sup_{v\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \vert\vert v\vert\vert_1 \vert\vert v\vert\vert_3^3 \leq C.
$$

This has been double posted by OP here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5004288/is-lim-limitsn-to-infty-v-1-v-33-bounded-over-all-vs-such-that .  This question should be closed.

To give an alternative answer to that of Surb, the function $v\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n v_i^3 v_j$ is continuous as a polynomial and $\Vert v\Vert_2=1$ is a compact subset. Then, the function restricted to the Euclidean in sphere $\mathbb{R}$ obtains a maximum, by Weierstrass's extreme value theorem.

But how does one find the maximum? So far i only seen that its bounded by the 1-norm but that is a bad bound as its a function of n.

I haven't done this myself yet, but I suspect using Lagrange multipliers would work in finding minima and maxima.@MtkelN
