Is $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \|v\|_1 \|v\|_3^3$ bounded over all v's such that $||v||_2 = 1$.
Is it true that a constant $C>0$ exists such that
$$
  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup_{v\in\mathbb{R}^n, \| v\|_2=1}
\| v\|_1 \| v\|_3^3 \leq C.
$$
Maximizing each term separately Does not work, as one gets
$$
lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup_{v\in\mathbb{R}^n, \vert\vert v\vert\vert_2=1}
\vert\vert v\vert\vert_1 \vert\vert v\vert\vert_3^3 \leq \sqrt{n}\cdot 1 = +\infty.
$$
On the other-hand $\vert\vert v\vert\vert_1$ is maximized when $v=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},...,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$, but this would yield
$$
\vert\vert v\vert\vert_1 \vert\vert v\vert\vert_3^3=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2}=1.
$$
So it does seems like the norms cancel each other out.
Also note that $C>1$ as if one considers $v=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},0.5, 0.5)$
we have that $\vert\vert v\vert\vert_1 \approx 1.7$ and $\vert\vert v\vert\vert_3^3=0.6$
so that $\vert\vert v\vert\vert_1 \cdot \vert\vert v\vert\vert_3^3 \geq 1.02$.
Also sorry for the re-post, the original question was written poorly and people suggested to pick $C=\sqrt{n}$ as that is (was fixed), but i need a bound that is independent of the dimension.
Thanks.
Edit:
So i understand that this indeed diverges.
The next question is does the logarithmic bound tight?

$\lim_{n\to\infty}$ on one side is never equal to a function of $n$ on the other side. It is unclear what you mean by the limit being $\leq\sqrt n.$

You can say $$\lim  f(n)\leq \lim\sqrt n =+\infty.$$ But it is meaningless and terrible abuse of notation to say $1\cdot\sqrt n=+\infty.$

Yes i meant $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Sorry for notation abuse with the limit,
It just that i was trying to make clear that bounding it by a function of N is not good.

If there is no constant bound that is independent of n i would like to know that too, perhabs a bound like log(n) also might work.

Abusing notation never makes anything clear/, because readers have to guess what you mean, and factor in the fact that you don't seem to know how to write it down correctly when they are trying to guess what you mean.

Here is a very simple example (nearly no calculations  are needed) which shows that  constant $C$  depends on $n.$ Moreover the order of the constant $C$ is equal $n^{1/2}.$
By homogeneity the problem is equivalent to $$ \|v\|_1\|v\|_3^3\le C\|v\|_2^4$$Consider the dimension $n+1$ and the vector $$v=(1,a,a,\ldots,a)$$  Then $$\|v\|_1=1+na,\|v\|_2^2=1+na^2,\ \||v\|_3^3=1+na^3$$ The
desired inequality is $$(1+na)(1+na^3)\le C(1+na^2)^2$$
Let $na^2=1.$ Then the inequality takes the form $$(1+a^{-1})(1+a)\le 4C$$ As $a=n^{-1/2}$ we get $$ (1+n^{1/2})(1+n^{-1/2})\le 4C$$ Clearly the inequality cannot hold for all $n$ as LHS is greater than $n^{1/2},$
hence $4C\ge n^{1/2}.$
Moreover the order of the constant $C$ is optimal since for any $v$ in the dimension $n$  we have $$\|v\|_1\le n^{1/2}\|v\|_2,\quad \|v\|_3\|\le \|v\|_2$$ Hence $$\|v\|_1\|v\|_3^3\le n^{1/2}\|v\|_2^4$$

Thanks, so the bound sqrt{n} is tight.
So now we know not to try from this angle.
Thanks a lot

No such constant exists. Here's a counterexample: consider the vector $v_n$ of length $n$ with $k-$th component
$$\left(v_n\right)_k=\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}}}~, ~~k=1,...,n$$
The normalization guarantees $\|v_n\|_2=1$. However, it is simple to see that
$$\|v_n\|_1=\frac{H_n}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}}}~,~~~~ \|v_n\|^3_3=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^3}}{(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2})^{3/2}}$$
and in the limit $n\to\infty$ the 3-norm converges to $\|v_n\|_3^3\to \zeta(3)/(\zeta(2))^{3/2}$, but the 1-norm diverges logarithmically.

Thanks for the answer, okay so a constant bound does not exists, is the logarithmic bound tight?
